# How to see the list of users with most reputation from foo tag

Tags: support, tags

Is there any way to see the list of users who have the most reputation from specific tag? 
For example I want to know the list of top 20 users which have the most reputation from command line tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/tags/command-line/topusers

or
[image]

Comment: Nice 'video' example :)  (How did you make it?)

Comment: [Licecap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/). Its meant for windows (which I use on my desktop), but runs fine in wine. Byzanz may work too but isn't as easy to use - [I have a question on SR, but I never found anything that works as well as licecap](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/710/linux-based-alternative-to-licecap)

Comment: Actually that's with more *score* in one tag no reputation.